# Bash script, cant find files

Tags: bash

I'm currently making some scripts, for my Centos 7 server, just to ease the process of having a server. I wrote this simple script, but it cant find the files or something like that....

```
#!/bin/bash
TIME=`date +%b-%d-%y`            # This Command will add date in Backup File Name.
FILENAME=backup-$TIME.tar.gz    # Here i define Backup file name format.
SRCDIR=/imp-data                    # Location of Important Data Directory (Source of backup).
DESDIR=/backups           # Destination of backup file.
tar -cpzf $DESDIR/$FILENAME $SRCDIR 

HOST=34.77.147.135                    # 2
USER=backupuser                       # 3
PASSWORD=backup                       # 4
ftp -inv $HOST <<EOF                  # 5
user $USER $PASSWORD                  # 6
lcd /backups                   # 7
mput *.tar.gz                         # 8
bye                                   # 9
EOF
#END
```

I expect the files getting uploaded to the given FTP server. But i'm getting this response:

```
local: # remote: #
local: #: No such file or directory
local: 8 remote: 8
local: 8: No such file or directory
221 Goodbye
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
ftp -inv $HOST <<EOF                  # 5
user $USER $PASSWORD                  # 6
lcd /backups                   # 7
mput *.tar.gz                         # 8
bye                                   # 9
EOF
```

Those "comments" aren't comments, they're part of the here-document started by `<<EOF`. For example, you're executing the command

```
mput *.tar.gz # 8
```

which fails because there are no files named `#` or `8`.